# Can I use a parallel port for RS-232 on linux?

Tags: python, serial-port, linux-device-driver

The RS232 (DB9) ports on my machine are full, so I would like to write to a LCD scoreboard using the Parallel port.  Making a cable with the correct pinout is not a problem.  I need to interface with the device using python.

Here is what I would like: an API similar to pySerial, so I can set the baud rate, and send a string to the scoreboard.  The scoreboard has no requirements for handshake or stop-bit, and is supposed to auto-detect.  I only need to write to the device, there is no need to read this port.

I am aware of pyParallel, has anyone used this for a similar application?  It appears that it is designed specifically for the Parallel (LPT) protocol.  My scoreboard will support RS232, RS422, RS485, or 20mA current loop.  I have done a fair bit of programming for RS232 devices, but my technical knowledge of serial communications if limited.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://pythonic-wisdom.blogspot.com/2008/11/accessing-parallel-port-on-linux-from.html

In short, yes you can, there are limits on achievable baudrate, maximum is via inb/outb, usable through python gpio module, around 300,000 operations a second, that is at 300kbaud if you only write to the port. Using linux /dev/parport is at least twice slower.

If you only need 9600 baud for example, it is quite possible to achieve reliable transmission, although you have to be prepared for your transmission or reception being interrupted by linux scheduling or python gc.

Another issue is voltage levels, you need -10 and +10 Vdc or so for rs-232, and you can't get negative voltage from parallel port, you'll have to add some hardware for that.

Perhaps you might or might not be able to fake rs422/rs485 differential signalling by setting a pair of pins (high, low) and (low, high) in turns.

Cannot tell you much about current loop in practice. That's something for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a USB connector on your computer you can use just use that with a converter: http://www.amazon.co.uk/USB-RS232-Converter-Cable/dp/B00077DJIQ

If you have no free USB ports, you can just use a USB hub.